# D3: How can I close a JSON file?

Tags: json, d3.js

When I update the contents of a JSON file they are not changed when I access them with d3.json. I suspect it may be necessary to CLOSE the file in order to refresh the contents but so far I have been unable to find how to do that. (I  rename the file and that works but clearly that is not desirable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because of your browser caching the JSON. That is, when you reload the page, the browser doesn't actually request the JSON again. Here's what you can do.

- Delete the browser cache or close and reopen the browser.
- Add a query parameter (which won't do anything) to the file name, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041603/how-to-prevent-the-browser-from-caching-a-json-file).
- Rename the file (as you've discovered already).
- If you have control over the webserver, you can configure it to prevent caching. See the answers to the question I've linked to above for more details.

Comment: Bless you! I had tried restarting the browser and also clearing the Drupal cache (I am using a Drupal site) but did not think to clear the Firefox cache. The dynamic query is a great solution.