# i18n files are cached in production

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have language service to achieve internationalization in my app. Basically it works ok in dev mode and `sometimes` in production as well.

My problem is that `sometimes` old version of my json files are cached in browser (If I'll open website in incognito mode everything is as expected).

I have my json files under `assets/i18n` directory

language.service.ts:

```
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LanguageService implements OnDestroy {
  activeLanguage: string = 'ka';
  data: any = {};
  data$: Subject<any>;
  dataSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private httpBackend: HttpBackend
  ) {
    this.data$ = new Subject();
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
  }

  loadLanguageFile(lang: string): void {
    if (lang) {
      this.activeLanguage = lang;
    }
    const path = `../assets/i18n/${this.activeLanguage}.json`;
    if (this.data[this.activeLanguage]) {
      this.data$.next(this.data[this.activeLanguage]);
    } else {
      this.dataSubscription = this.httpClient.get(path).subscribe(res => {
        this.data[this.activeLanguage] = res;
        this.data$.next(this.data[this.activeLanguage]);
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

language.module.ts:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LanguageService } from './language.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [LanguageService],
      useFactory: (language: LanguageService) => () => {
        return language.loadLanguageFile('ka');
      }
    }
  ]
})
export class LanguageModule {}
```

translate.pipe.ts:

```
import { OnDestroy, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '@app/core/services/language/language.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure: false
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  data: any;
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private languageService: LanguageService) {
    this.subscription = this.languageService.data$.subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
    });
  }

  transform(key: string): string {
    this.data = this.languageService.data[this.languageService.activeLanguage];
    return this.data && this.data[key] ? this.data[key] : key;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

sample use case:

```
<div>{{ text | translate }}</div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: if your files get cached  caches will get clear at some point.it's only a problem if you change translation files often.in such a case you can do something like this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041603/how-to-prevent-the-browser-from-caching-a-json-file .
basically you have to add some random query string values.

but how can you do this with angular .angular loads file internally you cannot change it.actually you can create a custom translate loader so you can change urls as you want https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader
but i think you can off caching from servers too.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Thanks for answer. your provided `http-loader` uses third party library called `ngx-translate`. At first I want to achieve the same solution by miself

Comment: ohh sorry .but wait considering this line  `const path = `../assets/i18n/${this.activeLanguage}.json`;` you don't need to do any hard work just append random generated value to end of the .json just like in the attached answer.like
const path = `../assets/i18n/${this.activeLanguage}.json?nocache=${myRandomValue}`; i hope this will work

Comment: sorry comment  format is messed due to backtick.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha well.. That one works as expected. thanks

Comment: great my pleasure

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha what about adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

We managed to work around this by utilizing our GitLab build process and the `environment.ts` files.

We updated our `environment.ts` file to include a "version" field:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  version: 'local' // replaced via the environment.prod.ts file via GitLab build script
};
```

We then also replaced our `environment.prod.ts` file to include the same version field but with a tag that's easy to replace:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  version: 'BUILD_TAG_VERSION'
};
```

We referenced these variables in our `app.module.ts` `HttpLoaderFactory`:

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/messages.', suffix: `.json?version=${environment.version}`},
  ]);
}
```

Then finally during our build step, we replace the BUILD_TAG_VERSION with the tag/branch name. In our case we use GitLab so in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file we ran the following script just before building the project:

```bash
sed -i "s/BUILD_TAG_VERSION/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
```

This replaced the BUILD_TAG_VERSION each time the project was built and guaranteed a new version of the file was pulled on any release.